# How to return a function by another function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return

I intend to create a checker function which will be used by another functions. The idea was simple: if the conditions are not fulfilled, stop the function by returning it.

This is the original code:

```
function awesome(){ 
    $a = "2";
    if ($a != "1"){return;} 
    echo "awesome"; 
}
```

It worked. Because the $a was 2, the function is returned and the word "awesome" is not appeared. However, there are several functions to check. To avoid repetition, i made it this way:

```
function test($var){
    if ($var != "1"){return;}
}

function awesome(){
    test("2");
    echo "awesome";
}

function awesomeagain(){
    test("3");
    echo "awesome";
}
```

but the word "awesome"s are appeared, and the both function awesome() and awesomeagain() are not returned. How to return those two by adding test() function?

Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: thanks for the editing. I'm really new here, still confused by the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test( $var ) {
    return ( $var == "1" );
}

function awesome() {
    if ( test("2") ) {
        echo "awesome";
    }
}

function awesomeagain(){
    if ( test("3") ) {
        echo "awesome";
    }
}
```

Fikry, try to re-learn the concept of `conditional`, this is the basic programming skill. Without it, you will make many buggy code and functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `test` function has to return a value, and you have to test this value in other functions. Something like this:

```
function test($var) {
  if ($var != "1")
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}
```

so, your code should be like this:

```
function awesome() {
  if (test("2"))
    echo "awesome";
}
```

But, if you want to avid checks, you can throw an exception. This should look like this:

```
function test($var) {
  if ($var != "1")
    throw new Exception();
}
```

and in other functions use

```
function awesome() {
  try {
    test("2");
    echo "yeah";
  } catch ($e) {}      
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! the 'test()' is worked but I made a little modification to the 'awesome()' so the code goes like this: 'if (test("2") == true)' then it works like a charm :D

Comment: In php good practice is to check value and type, so use if (test("2") === true), since in php this will return true ("2" == true), but ("2" === true) will return false.

Answer (score 1):

to return from the function you have to use `return` keyword

```
function test($var){
    if ($var == "1"){
        return TRUE;
    }
}

function awesome(){
    if (!test("2")){
        return FALSE;
    }
    echo "awesome";
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fYou probably shouldn't rely on another function stopping another function form running. Try this instead

```
function test($var){
    if ($var != "1"){return false;} return true;
}

function awesome(){
    if(test("2"))
    echo "awesome";
}

function awesomeagain(){
    if(test("3"));
    echo "awesome";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, it is quite similar to the previous response and with a very small modification it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($var) {
    if ($var != "1"){
        return "awesome";
    }
    // do something else when $var is not "1" here.
}
function awesome(){
    echo test("2");
}
function awesomeagain(){
    echo test("3");
}
```

That's it! PHP is awesome! :)

Comment: hmm.. i don't do that because the actions will be placed on awesome() and awesomeagain() and those actions are different. btw, yeah PHP is awesome. thanks for your response :D